# Why did my TeamCity build stop working?

Tags: git, build, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I have a TeamCity build configuration that has been working fine until recently. Suddenly, there is a build stuck in the queue that says it is not compatible with any agents. The reason given is:

> Implicit requirements: teamcity.build.branch defined in Parameter: BuildFormatSpecification

My BuildFormatSpecification parameter is defined thus:

> %MajorVersion%.%MinorVersion%.%PatchVersion%-%teamcity.build.branch%

That in turn is used in the Build Number Format field along with a build counter, like this:

> %BuildFormatSpecification%.%sharedBuildNumber.id4%

The idea is that the build number comes out like "1.0.0-develop.22" and includes the Git branch being built. This follows the rules for Semantic Versioning. This scheme has worked for me over a number of projects, but suddenly this one build is stuck and I can't figure out why.

Any ideas?

Comment: I had this error when my VSC root path ("Pull changes From") pointed to a physical directory instead of an URL. This worked on one agent, where the physical path was valid. All other agents did not have a repository at that path. After removing the only working agent, other agents were not able to ckeckout sources, resulting in `%teamcity.build.branch%` not being defined.
The solution was to change the path to a globally accessible URL of the repository.

Answer (score 65):

`teamcity.build.branch` is a [predefined build parameter](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Predefined+Build+Parameters#PredefinedBuildParameters-BranchRelatedParameters) but it is **only defined** when a [branch specification](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Working+with+Feature+Branches) is configured. Therefore, to fix your problem, make sure that your build step has a VCS root configured and add e.g. `+:refs/heads/(master)` as your branch specification.

From TeamCity's documentation on [Agent Requirements](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Agent+Requirements) and implicit requirements:

> Any reference (name in %-signs) to an unknown parameter is considered an "implicit requirement". That means that the build will only run on the agent which provides the parameters named.
>
> Otherwise, the parameter should be made available for the build configuration by defining it on the build configuration or project levels.

Comment: Also, Team City doesn't clear the problem once you fix it, you have to delete the build request and re-add it back.  Nice.  At least, on the version I'm using, which is a few builds back.   Ironically, if you set a default branch (required), and then leave the branch specification blank (shouldn't be required, as their description of it is: "Branches to monitor besides the default one " - which is 'none' just monitor the default one.  Also, if you switch from a single line here, to two full specifications, your branch displayed changes from 'develop' to /ref/head/develop' which

Comment: wastes space on the description,and adds junk to the build name - and was causing my builds to fail due to the name... No clue how to fix that..

Comment: You should ask a new question about branch names but the answer is to use parentheses around the part you want to be displayed, in my example it will be "master". See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/working-with-feature-branches.html#Logical-branch-name.