# How can I access Team City parameters in `build.cake`?

Tags: teamcity

I want to have part of my destination path in `build.cake` be based on the branch being built.  The top of my `build.cake` script says:

```
var branch = Argument("branch", "Master");
```

and I modified my Team City Build step to include

```
.\build.ps1 ... -Branch %teamcity.build.branch%
```

but Team City complains that I have no eligible agents

> Implicit requirements:  teamcity.build.branch defined in Build step:
>   Build

I'm new to TC and Cake so I'm likely missing something obvious.  How do I hook this up?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that `%teamcity.build.branch%` will give access to your branch name. However, this variable is blank unless you have a branch specification in your VCS root settings. In order to use say `master` as your `build.branch` parameter you need to add: `+:refs/heads/(master)` to your branch specification. Whatever is in between the parens will be put in the `build.branch` variable. If you might be building from multiple branches, you might have something like the following:

```
+:refs/heads/Release/(765/1.0)
+:refs/heads/Release/*
```

This would give your `build.branch` the name of branch as it appears in git after the `Release/`.

Also see Johan's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27829516/6222375

Comment: Thanks.  I don't see a "branch" specification.  On the VCS Root page in the General Settings section, Default Branch was set to "refs/heads/myBranchName".  Changing that top "+:refs/heads/(myBranchName)" causes the connection test to fail. (I'm using Git, if that matters.)

I'll check the other answer and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: Click `Show Advanced Options` at the bottom of the VCS Root page. The `branch specification` will be under the `Default Branch` box.